# Remove parts of strings from each string inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, rename

```
Primary_MathsJAN        
Primary_MathsFEB        
Primary_MathsMAR        
Primary_MathsAPR        
Primary_MathsMAY        
Primary_MathsJUNE       
Primary_MathsJULY       
Primary_MathsAUG        
Primary_MathsSEP        
Primary_MathsOCT        
Primary_MathsNOV        
Primary_MathsDEC
```

I have above key set after foreach the array.In here key list I want to remove JAN, FEB, MAR and etc and also the middle _ (underscore) then need the bellow result

```
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths   
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths       
Primary Maths
```

Is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: This will give you array with always the same values (if I understood correctly). So what about `array_fill(0, count($array), "Primary Maths")` or `array_fill(0, 12, "Primary Maths")`?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want

```
$array = array_map(
    function($val){ 
        return trim(str_replace(array("_","JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUNE","JULY", "AUG","SEP", "NOV","DEC"), " ", $val));
    }, 
    $array);
```

If you wanted to do it to an array of arrays you could just do:

```
$resultNew = array();

foreach($resultOld as $key=>$value)
{
    $resultNew[$key] = array_map(function($val){ return trim(str_replace(array("_","JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUNE","JULY", "AUG","SEP", "NOV","DEC"), " ", $val)); }, $value);
}
```

And `$resultNew` would have the values you want

Comment: is there anyway to remove _?

Comment: updated answer...just replace with a space, instead of an empty string then trim off the trailing space

Comment: It's easy to derive from the current solution, @DiliniWasana ! You can do it! (beaten by a few seconds, but my point stands still)

Comment: foreach($resultOld as $key=>$value)

{
$value = array_map(
    function($val){ 
        return trim(str_replace(array("_","JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUNE","JULY", "AUG","SEP", "NOV","DEC"), " ", $val));
    }, 
    $value);

foreach ($value as $key1 => $subjects) {

Comment: what are going getting out... an empty array or the array unaltered?

Answer (score 0):

I tried below case

```
<?php
$input = array("Supriya mahajan", "green mahajan", "blue mahajan", "yellow Gupta");
$input1  = array_map(function($val){ 
                        return trim(str_replace(array("mahajan"), " ", $val));
                     }, $input );
//   echo implode("_ ", $input); 
//    echo implode("<br>",substr_replace( $input,' ',3,3));
echo $input1[0];
echo $input1[1];
echo $input1[2];
echo $input1[3];
?>
```

How to show remaning array in one shot